# Android xml, how to add texts next to radiobuttons in a group?

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

I wanted to add descriptions for each radiobutton on the right, and a screenshot and my xml code is like this :

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton
                android:text="RadioButton1"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="This is Radiobutton1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton
                android:text="RadioButton2"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="This is Radiobutton2"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton
                android:text="RadioButton3"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="This is Radiobutton3"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
```

[image]

But this does not place my buttons into the group.
How can I add texts next to radiobuttons while functioning within group?

Comment: I tried to use a mix of two linear layouts, one for radiogroup and another for descriptions. It seemed to work but now I have an alignment (gravity) problem which is the description is not aligned to each of radiobuttons.

Comment: AFAIK, `RadioGroup` only looks at immediate children for `RadioButton` widgets, not the full hierarchy of possible children. Why are you not just putting "RadioButton1" and "this is Radiobutton1" in the text of the `RadioButton`?

Comment: I thought about it but I want the descriptions are aligned vertically each other and have different color and font size from those of radiobutton texts.

Comment: With respect to "different color and font size", you can do that with just the text in a `RadioButton`. Either use `Html.fromHtml()` to read in HTML with `<font>` tags for color and size, or create it yourself using `SpannableStringBuilder` and appropriate spans. With respect to "aligned vertically", if each `RadioButton` has the full caption, they will be aligned vertically by nature. If you mean aligned *horizontally* (two columns)... that could get tricky.

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar thing with the code below. I hope it helps  someone.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdAssociate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/associate_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/positra_text_h2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:checked="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/associate"
            android:textSize="@dimen/positra_text_h3"/>

    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdRevoke"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/revoke_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/positra_text_h2"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/revoke"
            android:textSize="@dimen/positra_text_h3"/>

    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdBlock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/block_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/positra_text_h2"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/block"
            android:textSize="@dimen/positra_text_h3"/>

</RadioGroup>
```